# How has __init__.py changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I am migrating my Python 2.7 stuff (which were working fine) to 3.4.3.

In my C:\Python34\Lib\MyLibs folder I have two files: `__init__.py` and `utils.py` copied over from the same folder in Python 2.7. In utils.py, I have this line near the top:

```
from __init__ import *
```

In 3.4.3, when I do a `import MyLibs.utils` I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named `__init__`

However, I can confirm that the code in `__init__.py` was executed successfully the first time that import statement was run.

May I know how I can import or access the variables declared in `__init__.py` in Python 3.

Comment: Why are you importing *from* the `__init__`?

Comment: My code is deployed on both Windows and Linux machines.  I have some platform speciic global variables kept in `__init__` so that that is the only file I have to customize per site.

Comment: @OldGeezer: it is name that is weird here; you'd not normally import from `__init__`; you'd import from the package name the `__init__.py` file lives in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 uses *absolute imports*, where an unqualified import is always looked up as a top-level package. You don't have such a package.

You'd use an explicit relative import instead:

```
from . import *
```

or use an absolute import

```
from packagename import *
```

Not that you should use `from __init__ import *` *in the first place* in Python 2 either. You'd use `from packagename import *` instead.

You can enable the absolute import model in Python 2 with:

```
from __future__ import absolute_imports
```

See [PEP 328 - *Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

You probably will have other issues however. Porting is not that trivial, read up on the issues in the [Porting to Python 3 book](http://python3porting.com/). This issue is  [a common migration problem](http://python3porting.com/problems.html).

Comment: Thanks.  `from MyLibs.__init__ import *` solved the problem.

Comment: @OldGeezer: Use `from MyLibs import *`. The `__init__.py` is there only because a directory cannot otherwise contain source code. Otherwise you'll get both `sys.modules['MyLibs']` and `sys.modules['MyLibs.__init__']` entries, so two sets of (separate) globals for your package. This can lead to all sorts of problems you'll have a hard time debugging later on.